# мультискролл flutter

Tags: flutter

Как сделать чтобы было видно сразу 2 скрола?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Scrollbar(
          isAlwaysShown: true,
          controller: controller,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: controller,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 3000,
                  height: 56,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  child: Text("wewe"),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Scrollbar(
                    controller: controller1,
                    isAlwaysShown: true,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: controller1,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 3000,
                        height: 2000,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        child: Text("1edds"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

Со скроллом в Flutter много проблем и issues по Scrollbar. К примеру:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/36474

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73697

и другие.

Если переключиться на flutter channel dev, то некоторые из проблем уже решены. По Вашему примеру, только увеличен размер для наглядности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сами элементы не пропадают, но уезжают. Все же хотелось бы, чтобы оба было видно и при скролле. А если глянуть, там ещё пачка issue касательно скроллбаров.

Так что легче написать свой костыль. Пример по Вашему коду:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  ScrollController _horizontalController = ScrollController();
  ScrollController _verticalController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _horizontalController,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 3000,
                    height: 56,
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text(
                        List<String>.generate(10, (index) => 'Header example')
                            .toString()),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: _verticalController,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 3000,
                        height: 2000,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        // MARK: - Для наглядности примера добавил
                        child: Text(List<String>.generate(
                                100,
                                (index) =>
                                    '${List<String>.generate(10, (index) => 'Header example').toString()}\n')
                            .toString()),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 56,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: OurCustomScrollbar(
                axis: Axis.vertical,
                controller: _verticalController,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OurCustomScrollbar extends StatefulWidget {
  // MARK: - Зачатки конфигурации направления, нужно дописать
  final Axis axis;
  final ScrollController controller;

  OurCustomScrollbar({
    @required this.axis,
    @required this.controller,
  });

  @override
  _OurCustomScrollbarState createState() => new _OurCustomScrollbarState();
}

class _OurCustomScrollbarState extends State<OurCustomScrollbar> {
  double _barOffset;
  bool _isDragInProcess;
  // MARK: - Размеры хардкод для примера, для красоты лучше высчитывать из размеров вьюшки и контента.
  double _barHeight = 50;
  double _barWidth = 20;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.controller.addListener(() {
      // MARK: - Я слежу за тобой, controller ;)
      _onChangePosition(widget.controller);
    });
    _barOffset = 0;
    _isDragInProcess = false;
  }

  double get barMaxScrollExtent => context.size.height - _barHeight;

  double get barMinScrollExtent => 0;

  double get controllerMaxScrollExtent =>
      widget.controller.position.maxScrollExtent;

  double get controllerMinScrollExtent =>
      widget.controller.position.minScrollExtent;

  void _onVerticalDragUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _barOffset += details.delta.dy;
      if (_barOffset < barMinScrollExtent) {
        _barOffset = barMinScrollExtent;
      }
      if (_barOffset > barMaxScrollExtent) {
        _barOffset = barMaxScrollExtent;
      }
      double translatedControllerDelta =
          details.delta.dy * controllerMaxScrollExtent / barMaxScrollExtent;
      double controllerOffset =
          widget.controller.position.pixels + translatedControllerDelta;
      if (controllerOffset < widget.controller.position.minScrollExtent) {
        controllerOffset = widget.controller.position.minScrollExtent;
      }
      if (controllerOffset > controllerMaxScrollExtent) {
        controllerOffset = controllerMaxScrollExtent;
      }
      widget.controller.jumpTo(controllerOffset);
    });
  }

  _onChangePosition(ScrollController controller) {
    if (_isDragInProcess) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      _barOffset =
          controller.offset * barMaxScrollExtent / controllerMaxScrollExtent;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onVerticalDragStart: (e) {
        _isDragInProcess = true;
      },
      onVerticalDragUpdate: _onVerticalDragUpdate,
      onVerticalDragEnd: (e) {
        _isDragInProcess = false;
      },
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: _barOffset),
        child: Container(
          height: _barHeight,
          width: _barWidth,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Ну и странно, что не сделают стандартный "независимый" скроллбар, который легко можно было бы прилепить куда угодно.