# Вертикальный и горизонтальный ScrollBar

Tags: flutter

Как сделать так чтобы было всегда видно сразу оба скролла, а не как на видео

```
Scrollbar(
   controller: controller,
         isAlwaysShown: true,
         child: SingleChildScrollView(
             controller: controller,
             scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
             child: Scrollbar(
                isAlwaysShown: true,
                controller: controller1,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: controller1,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 3000,
                    width: 3000,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Text("wehgjdh"),
                ),
           ),
       ),
   ),
)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [issue #70380](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70380) до сих пор открыто и прогресса не наблюдается, скорее даже наоборот. Проверил на `Flutter 1.26.0-18.0.pre.212` - ситуация ещё хуже.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [мультискролл flutter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1240790/%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb-flutter)